# Readings of the detectors at Japan and Izu-Bonin-Mariana Trenches

Tags: specific-reference, geophysics

Given the relevance of this subduction system, I would expect that a wide range of detectors (temperature, vibration, seismometers, whatever) are deployed in the depth of these trenches. What would be the canonical source at which one could access the readings of these detectors?

Comment: I think the technical name is "OBS"

Comment: Is this geophysics or just geology? I'm not an expert in the field, but it seems to me like the latter...

Comment: http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/maps/Northwestern_Pacific.shtml

Comment: Agreed it is just geology; but this is the closest stackexchange to ask...

Comment: I live in Japan and would also like to get more geophysics data about the first earthquake... Or get a sea bed picture of before/after. Definitely not easy!

Comment: My mechanics instructor in grad school was a observational (as opposed to theoretical) geophysicist and this kind of thing was right up his alley. I'm inclined to treat it as on topic, but possibly a list question. Can you say what you are interested in learning? That would give the problem a well defined correct answer.

Comment: It could be a [tag:reference-request] if the question is asking for the official, direct source to get data from the detectors.

Comment: Definitely it was a reference request. It was two years ago, but given that some new people seems to show interest, I will put some bounty points in.

Comment: I edited the question to make that a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of seafloor observatories making their data available freely and online is a vision and there are observatories being proposed by several of the major oceanographic institutions. Search for the term "seafloor observatory."

You might also take a look here, or contact the researchers:

[Realtime Data from the Deep Sea Floor Observatory](http://www.jamstec.go.jp/scdc/top_e.html) (off Kushiro-tokachi, off Muroto, off Hatsushima)